# R ifelse with warning message "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

Tags: r, if-statement

Suppose I have these two DFs.

```
df1 <- c("A","B","C","D") #The problem is D (both DFs have a different number of rows)
df2 <- c("A","B","Z")
```

My goal is to create a new variable in df3 based on the values in df1 and df2. So, if df1 = df2 then "Y" else "N".

```
df3$new_var <- ifelse(df1==df2, "Y","N")
```

I got this warning message when I run the code. Obviously, it will be fine if I got rid of the D in df1.

```
Warning message:
In df1 == df2 :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: Here's a quick intro to how R recycles vectors:
http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-lang/R-lang_41.html

Comment: `ifelse(df1 %in% df2, "Y", "N")` if you want an `ifelse` answer.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this without `ifelse`

```
c("N", "Y")[(df1%in% df2)+1]
#[1] "Y" "Y" "N" "N"
```